# Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined for begin document

Tags: input-encodings

I get the following error when trying to typeset my document:

```
./masterproef.tex:68: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `ascii'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.68 \begin{document}
```

I have no clue what could cause this. I get the exact same error for `\end{document}`.

Comment: Probably you have `\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}`, where `utf8` is most likely better than `ascii`.

Comment: Probably you are using a non ascii glyph, @€äöü, whatever. But you probably can't just change the input encoding, you have to change the encoding of the file as well.

Comment: @egreg The template I use had `\RequirePackage[ascii]{inputenc}`. Changing it to `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}` did the job. Thanks!